# What is the length of the pole given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

**MyApproach:**

Let the distance from the wall be x meter.

A/c to Pythagoras theorem,length of pole=$\sqrt{ x^2 + 64}$.

Second equation is that pole length now become $x+4$.

Now solving these both equation
=>$x+4=x+8$

I am getting nowhere to the result.But the Ans given is 10

> Is my approach right towards the problem.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Where does the ladder come from????

Comment: @Aniket Yes typo mistake.Edited the code

Comment: First line......distance of what from pole???? Wall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last step is a mistake. 
It should be $$x+4=\sqrt{x^2+64}$$ or, $$x^2+8x+16=x^2+64$$ or, $$8x=48$$ or, $$x=6$$
That is the answer. Length of the pole is $6\,\mathrm{m}$

Answer (score 1):

Man who told you that root of √x^2+64 is x+8 . You have nade a huge mistake there.